# Shrinking down whole HTML page

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to make my webpage responsive. Is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried multiple things, but the best I could do was make the logo at the top shrink but not the list with images in it that I use for my navigation.

```css
body {
    background-image: url("blob:https://imgur.com/afa5f824-36da-44c8-a6d0-1cd8c34d1167");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

#title {
 margin-left: 27%;
}

.imginlist {
 width: 80%;
}

/* MAIN MENU */
ul.a {
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

ul.a li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

.center {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

/* scaling */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexTWOcss.css">
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </meta>
  <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='images/favicon.ico' />
  <title>Homepage</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
  <!-- top of the website: The Banner + Navagation. -->
  <!-- Animal Crossing Logo DIV --> 
  <div class="center">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pR4Hl0x.png" alt="Animal Crossing Logo" id="title"/>
  <!-- Main Homepage Body --> 
  <ul class="a">
   <li>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Zi7NuYY.png" class="imginlist">
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LULfS54.png" class="imginlist" >
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PaxKNqq.png" class="imginlist">
      </li>
      <li>
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6WCbjck.png" class="imginlist">
       </li>
       <li>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Gqjl821.png" class="imginlist">
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>  
      </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is an open-ended question with multiple ways to proceed based on personal choice

Option 1: **Use Media Queries**

```
/* ----------- Google Pixel ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}
```

You can use such media queries to make it responsive for various sizes. You can find the entire list at [CSS Tricks - Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Option 2: **Use CSS-Grids**

```
.divParent
{
grid-template-colums: 0.5fr 1fr 0.5fr  //makes three columns
}

.divChild
{
grid-column: 1  //puts the content in first column
}
```

This is a CSS tag which was experimental from 2014 and in 2017 it got offical support from all browsers.
You can find more information on it's usage at [CSS Tricks - CSS Grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

As Richard already stated, the industry standard in generally media queries. Even with CSS grid you still create templates and use them in media queries as things will need to shift around based on screen size.